# jQuery compare select field values with an array before submitting form

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement, validation, multi-select

I'm new to jQuery but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a form with an multi select field named City and Zip,

I'm trying to get the values of this select field and compare it against a list of cities I have, if found any match jQuery will update the value of a hidden text field named city with these values and then submit the form. if no match found they will be redirected to a different website.

Same thing with the Zip codes, it will get the zip codes from the same field and see if it matchs any zip code from the list. if yes then update the zip code hidden field, if no then redirect them to another website.

Here is my code right now and It's not working.

```
$("#front-form").submit(function(event) {
 // Getting the values from the HTML select field
 var CityandZip = $("#citynzip").val();

 //Comparing the values with the cities list
 if (CityandZip === "City 1" || "City 2" || "City 3") {
    //Updaing the hidden field and submitting
    $("#HiddenCityField").val(CityandZip);
 //Comparing the values with the ZIP code list
 } else if (CityandZip === "11111" || "11112" || "11113") {
    //Updating the hidden ZIP code field
    $("#HiddenZipField").val(CityandZip);

 } else {
    //Redircting to a new site
    window.location.href = "http://www. redirecttowebsite.com"; 

 }

 });
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your ||s are wrong (CityandZip === "11111" || CityandZip === "11112" || CityandZip === "11113") Use a debugger and you'll find this kind of errors easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this out. I only did this for the cities check, not the zip code check, but its just building off the existing implementation.

```
$(function () {
    var arrCities = [ "Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh", "NYC" ];
    $("#front-form").submit(function (event) {
        $("#citynzip :selected").each(function (i, selected) {
            if ($.inArray($(selected).text().trim(), arrCities) > -1) {
                $("#HiddenCityField").val($(selected).text());
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "http://www. redirecttowebsite.com";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Going over what I did. First off, I have the base array of cities. I just threw some in here. Then I attach to the form submit event like you had. I then use my jquery selectors to select all elements of the citynzip element that are selected and perform a [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) on each of the selected elements. The condition checks if the selected item is in the array using jquery's [.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function to check if the selected item is in the base array to compare to, arrCities. If it is, add it to the hidden field.

I don't know how you want to handle if the selections are not in the array. Right now it looks like if any of the selections are not in the array, even if some are, that you want the page redirected and to only continue if all of the selections made by the user exist in the array. This should provide a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in

```
window.location.herf
```

Also, your ORs should look like this:

```
if (CityandZip === "City 1" || CityandZip === "City 2" || CityandZip === "City 3")
```

Finally, the way you're applying the value to the HiddenZipField is also incorrect.  The val() function takes the value you wish to set as a parameter, e.g. `val(CityAndZip)`

Comment: I'd just do `['City 1', 'City 2', 'City 3'].indexOf(CityandZip) !== -1`. It's a little cleaner.

Comment: Yep, I'd tend to do that too, but I think in this instance it's probably more helpful to the OP to point out why their code wasn't working.

Comment: I don't know where the issue is exactly, if I use console.log to return the values everything seems to work fine. But when I use the if statement nothing seems to work. Can't get any values back and the form is submitting anyway even when it should redirect.

Comment: Did you fix the if statements yet?  They're still wrong in your post at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#HiddenCityField").val() = CityandZip;
```

That won't work. You need to do:

```
$("#HiddenCityField").val(CityandZip);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work, below a code comparing the select input field to an array and then assigning the values to hidden fields.

```
$(function () {
var arrCities = [ "City 1", "City 2", "City 3" ];

var arrZip = [ "11111", "22222", "33333" ];

$("#front-form").submit(function (event) {
        $("#citynzip :selected").each(function (i, selected) {
            if ($.inArray($(selected).val(), arrCities) > -1) {
                $(selected).each(function(i, selected) {
                    $("#front-form").append("<input type='hidden' name='City[]' id='City' value='" + $(selected).val() + "' />")
                });
            } else if ($.inArray($(selected).val(), arrZip) > -1) {
                $(selected).each(function(i, selected) {
                    $("#front-form").append("<input type='hidden' name='Zip[]' id='Zip' value='" + $(selected).val() + "' />")
                });
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "http://www.website.com/"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks to everyone in here and with some research I was able to figure it out.